# Make list items in validationsummary in ASP.Net Core link to form fields?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, validation, section508

I'm trying to find out if there's a way to customize the individual bulleted items within a validation summary to point them to the form fields.  We were able to do this with an earlier webforms application, but maybe there was custom JS involved, I can't recall.  I'm just looking for some suggestions for this, it seems like it might require some custom JS to get working, but I'm hoping there's some package that might make this a bit easier.  This is for accessibility reason, or UI person suggested this was something that was needed for 508 compliance.

Comment: I don't find any related library to help you custom frontend validation, From [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0), you need to write js by yourself.

Comment: You need to use custom JavaScript. Identify validation errors, generate custom error messages with links, and display these messages in place of the default validation summary. There are no ready-made packages for this custom coding is required.